# Deduct Timer Count Every Page Refresh (Vanilla Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am absolutely a noob when it comes to Javascript so I hope someone can help me please. I made a very simple Vanilla JS + HTML code that counts the number of times that it reaches 10 seconds (10 seconds = 1 count). This code will also refresh the page `onmouseleave` and when I change tab using `window.onblur`. My problem is that every time the page refreshes, the counter will go back to zero. What I want is that for the counter to deduct just one (or a specific number of) count every page refresh instead of completely restarting the count to zero. Please help me with Vanilla Javascript only and no JQuery (because I am planning to use this code personally and offline). Thank you in advance.

For those who may wonder what's this code is for, I want to create this to encourage myself to stay away from my computer for a certain period everyday. Like, if I can stay away from my computer for 100 counts, then I can use my computer freely after. I am addicted to the internet and I want to make this as my own personal way of building self-control.

Here is my code:

```
<style>
label {
  color: orange;
  }

p {
  border-radius: 0px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Consolas !important;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  outline: none;
  line-height: 0.25 ;
  }
</style>
<body onmouseleave="window.location.reload(true)">
<p>You have earned <label id="pointscounter">00</label> point/s.</p>

<script>

var PointsLabel = document.getElementById("pointscounter");
var totalCountPoints = 0;
setInterval(setTimePoints, 10000);

function setTimePoints() {
  ++totalCountPoints;
  PointsLabel.innerHTML = pad(totalCountPoints);
}

function pad(val) {
  var valString = val + "";
  if (valString.length < 2) {
    return "0" + valString;
  } else {
    return valString;
  }
}
</script>

<script>
var blurred = false;
window.onblur = function() { blurred = true; };
window.onfocus = function() { blurred && (location.reload()); };
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: You will need to store the count in e.g. `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` to have it persist across page loads.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. I am not really good when it comes to editing Javascript and I am just in the beginner stage of learning it. I am familiar with `localStorage` and `sessionStorage` but I really do not have an idea how to implement it in the code. Can you please help me edit my existing code? And after setting up the `localStorage` and `sessionStorage`, is there a way that we can deduct the total counted points every page refresh? Thank you in advance for the help @AKX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Storage

If you want the data to survive a reload, you need to save it somewhere. There are multiple options you can use. I used `localStorage`. You can learn more about it here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp. `localStorage` even survives closing the Browser Tab.
If you want to reset the data in a new session, you can use `sessionStorage` (just replace `localStorage` with `sessionStorage`): https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_sessionstorage.asp.

#### What I did:

**Save data on blur**

If a blur-event occurs, the data is saved.
I also stopped the interval because there is no need for the interval anymore.

**`blurred` variable**

There is (currently?) no need for this variable.
The only usecase seems to be:

```js
window.onfocus = function() {
  blurred && location.reload();
};
```

*To my knowledge* you don't need this variable here.

**Comming back**

If the user already has points in localstorage, the current Points are calculated based on the points in localstorage. It currently deducts 1 point.

**Using onmouseleave**

I replaced the `location.reload(true)` on the body-tag with a function call. Everytime the mouse leaves, it calls this function. This function calls the `onBlur` function. The `onBlur` function is there, to ensure, that both `window.onblur` and `onmouseleave` do the same thing (save & stop). After the `onBlur` function is called, an EventListener is added to wait for `mouseenter`. When the mouse is seen again, we can reload the page with the `onFocus` function. It wouldn't reload the page as soon as the mouse left, because the timer would start (bc of reload), even if the mouse wasn't on the document.

#### Todo:

- There is currently no check to see, if a the mouse in on the document after a reload. The timer will begin, even if the mouse isn't on the document.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />

      <style>
        label {
          color: orange;
        }
        
        p {
          border-radius: 0px;
          color: black;
          text-decoration: none;
          font-family: Consolas !important;
          font-size: 16px;
          font-weight: normal;
          outline: none;
          line-height: 0.25;
        }
      </style>
    </head>

    <body onmouseleave="mouseLeft()">
      <p>You have earned <label id="pointscounter">00</label> point/s.</p>

      <script>
        var PointsLabel = document.getElementById("pointscounter");

        var totalCountPoints = 0;

        // Calculate Points if user has already collected points
        if (localStorage.getItem("points") !== null) {
          // You can change, how many points to deduct
          const pointsToDeduct = 1;

          var tempPoints = localStorage.getItem("points");
          totalCountPoints = tempPoints - pointsToDeduct;

          // Reset to 0 if points now negative
          if (totalCountPoints < 0) {
            totalCountPoints = 0;
          }

          PointsLabel.innerHTML = pad(totalCountPoints);
        }

        // need to save, to stop/clear it later
        var timePointsInterval = setInterval(setTimePoints, 10000);

        function setTimePoints() {
          ++totalCountPoints;
          PointsLabel.innerHTML = pad(totalCountPoints);
        }

        function pad(val) {
          var valString = val + "";
          if (valString.length < 2) {
            return "0" + valString;
          } else {
            return valString;
          }
        }

        function mouseLeft() {
          onBlur();
          document.addEventListener("mouseenter", onFocus);
        }

        function onBlur() {
          // save Current Points:
          localStorage.setItem("points", totalCountPoints);

          //stop the timer
          clearInterval(timePointsInterval);
        }
        function onFocus() {
          location.reload();
        }

        // Blur Detection
        var blurred = false;
        window.onblur = function () {
          // [-] blurred = true;
          onBlur();
        };
        window.onfocus = function () {
          // [-] blurred && location.reload();
          onFocus();
        };
      </script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Hello @Quixelation. Thank you for the code. I tried it by saving the file in a notepad with an HTML format to check it in a browser. It seems like it goes back to 1 instead of just deducting 1 point out of the total points every page refresh. But I really appreciate your help. I will try to check if what else are wrong with the code. But your code is really a great help for me to move forward with this.

Comment: @Quinxelation I apologize. I was wrong. It works. But there seems to be a very very long delay for the `localStorage` to save the number of counts. So, if I leave the tab `onmouseleave` and the page refreshes, the count will go back to the last count that was saved in `localStorage`. I also tried `sessionStorage` and the issue is the same. I will try to look around online for any workaround to save the count in `localStorage` like every 500 ms. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi @PeterBrown . I totally forgot the onmouseleave event. If this event gets called the data isn't even saved in localStorage. The page currently just reloads. I will edit my previous answer to implement the event.

Comment: Sorry for replying late @Quixelation. Thank you for such a great help with this. I really appreciate everything.